# Replace the regular foreach with stream/lambda/method references

Tags: java

I have a `Class` `Foo` that has a `Constructor` that sets `name` and `id`.

In another `Class` I have a `List<String>` of messages where I can extract the `name` and `id`.

I'm able to successfully set the `Constructor` by looping through the list using regular `foreach` loop. How do I achieve this using `Stream` `Java 8` or `Lambda` or `Method References`

```
public class ConstructorTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
    userList.add("username1_id1");
    userList.add("username2_id2");
//I want to replace the below foreach loop with stream/lambda/methodreferences
    for (String user : userList) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(getName(user), getId(user));
        fooList.add(foo);
    }
}

private static String getName(String user) {
    return user.split("_")[0];
}

private static String getId(String user) {
    return user.split("_")[1];
}
}
```

Foo Class:

```
public class Foo {

public Foo(String name, String id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

private String name;
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
userList.stream().map(user -> new Foo(getName(user), getId(user)).forEach(userList::add)
```

Or this

```
userList.forEach(user -> userList.add(new Foo(getName(user), getId(user))))
```

Comment: I did `userList.stream().parallel().map(user -> new Foo(getName(user), getId(user))).forEach(fooList::add);

  fooList.forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.getName() + "   " + user.getId())); ` and I got null pointer exception

Comment: @user1629109 Don't add to a list with a parallel stream.

Comment: Why so? Any particular reason? sometimes it works and sometimes it returns "NPE"

Comment: Ok. thanks. Is there an alternative to user `parallel()`? I have a very big list to process. Should I user `Vector`?

Comment: @user1629109 If you have a question about thread-safe lists, you should refer to the documentation here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel) which specifically says that you can't add to an ArrayList in parallel. If you have a question about optimization, you should create a follow up question on codereview.stackexchange. You shouldn't be asking follow-up questions to my answer in the comments.